# Search a word in XML and display that node only using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have created a input text and submit button in HTML page.
In the HTML page,

Question 1:  if I type "WHAT is animal" and click submit, then i need a js alert should show "lion, tiger, elephant, dog, cat"

Question 2: if type " what are pet animals" and click submit, then I need a js alert should show `dog, cat` only.

```
<database>
    <content>
        <keywords><![CDATA[wild animal]]></keywords>
        <description><![CDATA[ lion, tiger, elephant]]></description>
    </content>
    <content>
        <keywords><![CDATA[pet animal]]></keywords>
        <description><![CDATA[dog, cat]]></description>
    </content>
</database>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). SO is **not a free coding or tutorial service**! You have to show that you've put some efford into solving your own problem.

Comment: Sure let me try and share my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had nothing else to do, so I went ahead and wrote a functional script. Explanation can be found in the comments of the code.

```js
/* XML String */
const XMLString = '<database>'+
 '<content>'+
  '<keywords><![CDATA[wild animal]]></keywords>'+
  '<description><![CDATA[ lion, tiger, elephant]]></description>'+
 '</content>'+
 '<content>'+
  '<keywords><![CDATA[pet animal]]></keywords>'+
  '<description><![CDATA[dog, cat]]></description>'+
 '</content>'+
'</database>';

/* Search function */
function searchXML(searchString){
 const parser = new DOMParser();
 // Parse XML string with the DOM parser
 const xmldoc = parser.parseFromString(XMLString,"text/xml");

 // Get all content tags
 const contentEles = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("content");

 // Empty array to save result
 let result = [];

 // Loop through each content element
 for(let i = 0; i < contentEles.length; i++){
  // Get the keywords inside the keywords element
  const keywords = contentEles[i].childNodes[0].textContent.split(" ");

  // Loop through each keyword
  for(let y = 0; y < keywords.length; y++){
   // Create regex that matches whole words only
   const keyword = '\\b'+keywords[y]+'\\b';
   const regex = new RegExp(keyword,"i");

   // Search the searchString if it contains a keyword
   if(searchString.search(regex) !== -1){
    // Push the contents of the description element to the result
    // array if a keyword was found
    result.push(contentEles[i].childNodes[1].textContent);
   }
  }
 }

 // Convert the result array to a string and alert it
 alert(result.join());
}

/* Add event listener to html document fully loaded */
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event){
 const form = document.getElementById('search');

 /* Add event listener to form submit */
 form.addEventListener("submit", function(e){
  // Prevent form from submitting
  e.preventDefault();

  // Perform search
  searchXML(document.getElementById('searchXML').value);
  
  // Empty the form
  form.reset();
 });
});
```

```html
<form id="search">
 <label>Search: </label>
 <input type="text" id="searchXML"/>
 <input type="submit" value="Search"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

JSAnimalName:       function myFunction() {var l_animal = document.getElementById("animal").value;
            if('WHAT is animal'==l_animal){alert('lion, tiger, elephant, dog, cat');        }else if('what are pet animals'==l_animal){alert('dog, cat');}else{alert('Wrong input');            }}